Как проверить правильность команды для CMD (Python)
при создании своего проекта у меня возник вопрос, а можно ли заранее проверить выполниться ли команда в CMD без ошибки?
Конечно можно использовать конструкцию try-except, но тогда если команда не вернет ошибку, она будет выполнена.

Нельзя/очень сложно/зависит от команды. Экстремальный пример: команда сборки приложения, или команда, применяющая миграцию к базе данных.
